# Exclude specified element from foreach

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am looking to exclude some element(s) during for-each using a result map from imported JSON data.
I suspect the tests I am running might work when running XML as source, but not with JSON as source.

**JSON data:**

```
<data>
{
  "storage": {
    "pencils": 12,
    "milk": 8,
    "rulers": 4
  }
}
</data>
```

**

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:storage="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:office="http://www.example.com/2"
  xmlns:item="http://www.example.com/3"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <storage:one>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)"/>
    </storage:one>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='storage']">

    <!-- Startbase -->
    <!-- <xsl:for-each select="*"> -->

    <!-- Test[2] -->
    <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name() != 'milk']">
    <!-- Test[3] -->
      <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::*/@key=milk)]">

      <xsl:element name="item:{@key}">
        <xsl:attribute name="office">plant-1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<storage:one xmlns:item="http://www.example.com/3"
             xmlns:office="http://www.example.com/2"
             xmlns:storage="http://www.example.com/1">
   <item:pencils office="plant-1">12</item:pencils>
   <item:milk office="plant-1">8</item:milk>
   <item:rulers office="plant-1">4</item:rulers>
</storage:one>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<storage:one xmlns:item="http://www.example.com/3"
             xmlns:office="http://www.example.com/2"
             xmlns:storage="http://www.example.com/1">
   <item:pencils office="plant-1">12</item:pencils>
   <item:rulers office="plant-1">4</item:rulers>
</storage:one>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the for-each element to following will exclude the specified element:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[not(@key='milk')]">
```